# How to fix Invalid Content-Type:text/html in SOAP client using Java

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, saaj

I am trying to send a request to http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx

I tried running this SOAP Webservice Call but getting the error below. 
Where can I edit the Context type

```
import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;


public class Main2
{

        private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception
        {
                MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
                SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
                SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();


                // SOAP Envelope
                SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
                envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("web", "http://www.webserviceX.NET");

                // SOAP Body
                SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
                SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("GetCitiesByCountry", "web");
                SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("CountryName", "web");
                soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("Brazil");

                soapMessage.saveChanges();

                // Check the input
                System.out.println("Request SOAP Message = ");
                soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
                System.out.println();
                return soapMessage;
        }

        /**
         * Method used to print the SOAP Response
         */
        private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception
        {
                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
                System.out.println("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
                transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
        }

        /**
         * Starting point for the SAAJ - SOAP Client Testing
         */
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
                try
                {
                        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
                        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

                        String url = "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL";
                        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

                        soapConnection.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        System.err.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

Here is the output in the Console:

```
Request SOAP Message = 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><web:GetCitiesByCountry><web:CountryName>Brazil</web:CountryName></web:GetCitiesByCountry></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
Feb 16, 2017 8:54:40 PM com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl identifyContentType
SEVERE: SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be an error message instead of a SOAP message
Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:148)
    at com.hpe.snow.utils.snowwstester.Main2.main(Main2.java:109)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:86)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:328)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
    ... 1 more

CAUSE:

com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:86)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:328)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
    at com.hpe.snow.utils.snowwstester.Main2.main(Main2.java:109)

CAUSE:

com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:86)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:328)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
    at com.hpe.snow.utils.snowwstester.Main2.main(Main2.java:109)
```

What needs to be added? Or Edited?

UPDATE

I inserted

```
        soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("Brazil");

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/html");


        soapMessage.saveChanges();
```

but I got error

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection post
SEVERE: SAAJ0010: Unable to read response
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:116)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2707)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2702)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.readFully(HttpSOAPConnection.java:567)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:314)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
    at com.hpe.snow.utils.snowwstester.Main2.main(Main2.java:75)
Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to read response: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:148)
    at com.hpe.snow.utils.snowwstester.Main2.main(Main2.java:75)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to read response: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:338)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
    ... 1 more

CAUSE:

com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to read response: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:338)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
    at com.hpe.snow.utils.snowwstester.Main2.main(Main2.java:75)

CAUSE:

com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to read response: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:338)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
    at com.hpe.snow.utils.snowwstester.Main2.main(Main2.java:75)
```

Comment: I'm not sure but at the client you have to set the content type too in rquest header

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiXoNCT15TSAhWHKo8KHQa9DHkQFggfMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F22176769%2Funsupported-content-type-text-plain-charset-iso-8859-1&usg=AFQjCNFO47_Pe7LpyRg9ltS9wpzUTvsK8A&sig2=VzbTm7NMEGsem5_l_Qv7bQ&bvm=bv.147134024,d.c2I

Comment: Where shall I put it?

Comment: I tried putting     headers.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/html"); but failed

Answer (score 1):

I fixed issues in your code here is how you should call. I tested and its working.

```
    import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
     import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
     import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
     import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
     import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
     import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
     import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
     import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
     import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;
     import javax.xml.transform.Source;
     import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
     import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
     import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

    public class Main2 {

      private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();

        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("web", "http://www.webserviceX.NET");

        // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("GetCitiesByCountry", "web");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("CountryName", "web");
        soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("Brazil");
        MimeHeaders header = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        header.setHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry");

        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        // Check the input
        System.out.println("Request SOAP Message = ");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);

        return soapMessage;
    }

    /**
     * Method used to print the SOAP Response
     */
    private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
        System.out.println("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
    }

    /**
     * Starting point for the SAAJ - SOAP Client Testing
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

            String url = "http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx";

            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

            printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);

            soapConnection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```